# Help me to understand why my question is wrong

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question about the differences of rails 3.2 and 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995650/rails-3-2-vs-4-0?noredirect=1#comment24555623_16995650) and for my surprise, it was closed very quickly. This can only means that my question is a really bad one, and yet I can't understand why.

It is really important for me to understand why my question is wrong, because I can also vote for close questions and I might have been done a bad job.

While some people tried to help me to understand why this question is highly based on opinion, they failed. Maybe one example of a can help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

General questions aimed at many things means many reasons to close. Focus is what works here. Stay on a point. Don't add things as you think of them.

You need to stick to one solid question.

Then, read the release notes on Rails 4. This shows both differences in the new version and old as well as having done some research. Your question lacks this on first go.

The other two questions are opinions and environment based. The answers will depend on a set up. Some apps will have no trouble updating. Some will. Some should migrate now. Some don't have to because they're not affected by any of the changes or fixes. It depends. And that doesn't work here.

When the question is vague or holding back details and an answer such as "maybe" is perfectly valid, that's also a sign your question is not constructive.